# Trying to configure UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, diffabledatasource

```
func configureDataSource() {
    print("configure dataSource!!!")

    dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource
      <Section, StoryItem>(collectionView: storyCollectionView) {
        (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, storyItem: StoryItem) -> UICollectionViewCell? in

    print("try creating a collection view cell!")
```

The print statement showing that the function was called appears in the console, but the code within the { for `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` does not run.

Any suggestions on where to troubleshoot next? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be a lot more code than that. You need to *populate* the diffable data source with some *data*. Otherwise, the number of items in your collection view is zero and there is no need to generate any cells.

A typical dance (usually in `viewDidLoad`) will go something like this:

```
// make the data source
self.datasource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String,String>(collectionView:self.collectionView) { 
    cv,ip,s in
    return self.makeCell(cv,ip,s) // return cell
}
// give it a supplementary view provider if you have headers/footers
self.datasource.supplementaryViewProvider = { cv,kind,ip in
    return self.makeSupplementaryView(cv,kind,ip) // return view
}
// give the data source some data (here, my data is sitting in `sections`)
var snap = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String,String>()
for section in sections {
    snap.appendSections([section.0])
    snap.appendItems(section.1)
}
self.datasource.apply(snap, animatingDifferences: false)
```

Comment: Ahh yes, I had everything set up right but I hadn't sent any data into appendItems yet. :facepalm emoji: - Thanks!